# как создать мультипроцесс

Tags: python, python-3.x

При выполнении определённой функции, программа не обрабатывает те строки кода, которые находятся после этой функции, пока она не завершиться. Можно ли это обойти?

Comment: Запустить функцию в отдельном потоке/процессе?

Comment: Можно подробнее как это сделать, если функция тесно связанна с остальным кодом?

Comment: Нужно отвязать функцию от остального кода, иначе многопоточная модификация состояния очень легко порушит всю программу

Answer (score 0):

Вам может помочь модуль `threading` или `multiprocessing`.

Выбирать стоит, исходя из технических характеристик Вашего устройства, если 2 и более ядер, то рекомендуется `multiprocessing`, в ином случае - `threading`.
Также, при 1 ядре стоит понимать, что скорость исполнения может ухудшится почти в 2 раза, так как Python оптимизирован на работу в 1 потоке с GIL.

***Пример на потоках:***

```py
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep


def func():
    i = 0
    while i < 4:
        print('Ni!')
        i += 1
        sleep(1)


t = Thread(target=func)
t.start()
sleep(2)
print('Spam!')
```

*stdout:*

```html
Ni!
Ni!
Spam!
Ni!
Ni!
```

Чтобы переписать пример под `multiprocessing` менять почти ничего не надо. Единственное, придётся использовать конструкцию `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

***Пример на процессах:***

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=func)
    p.start()
    ...
```

***UPD:***
Для связи элементов можете использовать (перед этим [погуглить](https://lmgtfy.com/?q=Queue+Python+3)) `Queue` и его аналог для процессов `multiprocessing.Queue`.